# How do I feed the language culture thread into the helper class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, globalization, currentculture

With asp.net MVC 2, I have been trying to get Matt Hawley's Localization helper to work in my web application, but I am getting stuck feeding a null into the Language string variable. I can't figure out why I am doing this.

```
namespace MvcLocalization
{
public abstract class LocalizedControllerBase : Controller
{
    public String LanguageCode { get; private set; }

    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        LanguageCode = requestContext.RouteData.Values["languageCode"].ToString();

        if ( !AppConfig.SupportedLanguages.Contains(LanguageCode) )
            LanguageCode = AppConfig.DefaultLanguageCode;

        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(LanguageCode);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

        base.Execute(requestContext);
    }
}
```

}

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: could you post your routes you're mapping? You can find these in your Global.asax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to swap cultures using MIKEBLOG's code in his/her awesome blog post       http://helios.ca/2009/05/27/aspnet-mvc-and-localization/

thanks

Paul